How to optimize function to generate employee roster?
I have created a function in Python to generate a roster by selecting a pair of inspectors each for two teams (team A and B) each week for the whole year. The function accepts two lists, one list is optional. A pair cannot be formed exclusively from list2, the optional list. The count of each person in each team should be almost the same.
The function works except that there is little variety in the selection process. I want different pairs to be selected for the same team until all possible pairs are exhausted. I want each person to have a different partner each time he/she is selected for team A. For example, if Kay and Pat are selected in team A for week 4, Kay should have a different partner the next time Kay is selected in team A.
This is the code:
import pandas as pd
import random

def generate_roster(list1, list2=None):
    if list2:
        people = list1 + list2
    else:
        people = list1

    # Ensure there are at least 4 people to form two pairs for Team A and Team B
    if len(people) < 4:
        raise ValueError("There should be at least four people to form two pairs for Team A and Team B.")

    # Initialize dictionaries to keep track of when each person was last selected for Team A and Team B
    last_selected_a = {person: -2 for person in people}  # Start with -2 to allow immediate selection
    last_selected_b = {person: -2 for person in people}

    # Initialize dictionaries to count appearances in Team A and Team B
    appearances_a = {person: 0 for person in people}
    appearances_b = {person: 0 for person in people}

    roster = []

    for week in range(1, 53):  # 52 weeks in a year
        valid_selection = False

        while not valid_selection:
            # Sort people by their appearances in Team A and Team B to prioritize those with fewer appearances
            sorted_people_a = sorted(people, key=lambda p: (appearances_a[p], last_selected_a[p]))
            sorted_people_b = sorted(people, key=lambda p: (appearances_b[p], last_selected_b[p]))

            selected_people = []

            # Select two people for Team A ensuring no pair is formed exclusively from list2
            for _ in range(2):
                for person in sorted_people_a:
                    if person not in selected_people and (person in list1 or any(p in list1 for p in selected_people)):
                        selected_people.append(person)
                        break

            # Select two people for Team B ensuring no pair is formed exclusively from list2
            for _ in range(2):
                for person in sorted_people_b:
                    if person not in selected_people and (person in list1 or any(p in list1 for p in selected_people[2:])):
                        selected_people.append(person)
                        break

            team_a = selected_people[:2]
            team_b = selected_people[2:]

            # Check if this is the first week or if the same person is selected for the same team in successive weeks
            if week == 1 or (not (set(team_a) & set(roster[-1]['Team A'].split(', ')) or set(team_b) & set(roster[-1]['Team B'].split(', ')))):
                valid_selection = True

        # Update the last selected week for each person
        for person in team_a:
            last_selected_a[person] = week
            appearances_a[person] += 1
        for person in team_b:
            last_selected_b[person] = week
            appearances_b[person] += 1

        roster.append({
            'Week Number': week,
            'Team A': ', '.join(team_a),
            'Team B': ', '.join(team_b)
        })

    df_roster = pd.DataFrame(roster)
    return df_roster


Please share a [mre]

The problem isn't entirely clear. We can infer from the code, but since you're asking about the code, that may not work. There are 2 groups of people to select from, but's unclear what you mean by 'one list is optional'? You want to divide people into two groups, but also into pairs - are the groups made up of pairs? What should happen to the last person in case of an odd number of people? It appears you want rosters where people spend about the same amount of time in team A as in team B, but also have the most varied selection of partners. Can you share an example with a good solution?

you need to implement a pairing mechanism for keep track

Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  This would be better asked on the CodeReview exchange.

You need to implement a pairing mechanism for keep track of pairs
used_pairs_a = set()
used_pairs_b = set()

and within valid selection you can add ( remember to add ValueError for exceptions)
possible_pairs_a = list(combinations(sorted_people_a, 2))
possible_pairs_a = [pair for pair in possible_pairs_a if pair not in used_pairs_a]
team_a = None

then Update the last selected week and used pairs
for person in team_a:
last_selected_a[person] = week
appearances_a[person] += 1

used_pairs_a.add(team_a)

update your code accordingly for both teams then you can meet your expectations
